# vagrant powershell translation missing: en.vagrant_winrm.errors.winrm_not_ready

Tags: powershell, vagrant

Here's what I get when I try `vagrant powershell`:

```
translation missing: en.vagrant_winrm.errors.winrm_not_ready
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix this yet?

Answer (score 1):

press **windows+R** and type **services.msc** and then search for 
**"windows remote management"** ,**start/restart** the service and restart the **machine**